# Cant disable ime input mode in google chrome

Tags: input, ime

i cant disable ime input (japanese input) in chrome
i try :

```
 style="ime-mode:disabled"
```

also try textbox type :

```
 type="tel"
```

none of those work for me .

Comment: type tel does not disable the ime mode. It just change the priority, so that alphabet letters are selected by default (similar to ime-mode inactive not disabled).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, ime-mode does not work in Chrome.
In addition, it will be obsolete in CSS3(http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-css3-ui-20150224/#input-method-editor).

Let's give up.